# JasperReports & iReport: Generate a Message or Popup if report of hyperlink is empty

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport

I created a few reports in iReport which are linked together. I have one main report which contains three links to other reports.

Through the database structure it is possible that the linked report is empty.

For example:
report1 contains a links to report2. the parameter is number 1.
report1 has dataset 1.
report 2 has dataset 2. dataset 2 has no entries for number 1.

If you use report 1 it shows the link to report 2, but if you click on the link of report 2, you get the message that it is empty.

Is there a possibilty to generate a pop up which says, the report has no data but the user stays on report 1?
OR
Is there a possibility, that the link to report 2 is no link, if the report is empty?

Comment: Generating no link will be easier. @davioooh's suggestion is good. You don't necessarily need a subreport, but a subreport would work. The key is that in Report1 you need to determine if Report2 will have data either my modifying your query or by adding additional queries.

Answer (score 2):

This is an hypothesis...

You could use a sub-report to render the link to your **report 2**.

In your sub-report you will count how many rows are in your **report 2**. If `row count > 0` sub-report will show the link, otherwise will be an empty (sub)report.

Take a try.